# ActiveRecord::Store with fieldnames taken from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose I have two models, Person and Field in an HR system.  I want to allow users of the system to add custom attributes to the Person model, by creating a Field for it.  So my Person model would contain a line something like

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :fields, accessors: Field.all.pluck(:name), coder: JSON
end
```

This however doesn't work, because the class gets cached and new fields aren't therefore added.  Normally I would look to use a Proc or lambda but that won't work here.
Is there a simple solution to this problem which doesn't rely on adding a gem? Can I do this without using ActiveRecord Store, and with a serialized column, but where I retain the ability to do validations and track changes to the attributes?

Comment: looks like a good case for [rails settings](https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings)

Comment: Having tried rails settings, this isn't going to work for me and doesn't answer the question.  I need the data to be stored in the people table, not an associated table and I want to do this without adding another gem to the project.

Comment: Adding a method which does `Object.send(:remove_const, :Person)` and then `load 'person.rb'` in an after_commit hook on the Field class works, but surely that is very brute force and likely to cause issues in production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :fields, coder: JSON

  after_initialize :add_accessors_for_field_names

  def add_accessors_for_field_names
    field_names.each do |field_name|
      singleton_class.class_eval do
        store_accessor :fields, field_name
      end
    end
  end

  def field_names
    Field.all.pluck(:name)
  end
end
```

Comment: That does precisely what I wanted! I was unaware of class_eval - I should learn some more metaprogramming!  Thanks for this